# Passing form variable into Php Query

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to get a variable from a form on my page 1 into a query  I have made on page 2 so that when the query works it will use the variable entered on page 1

Page 1 Form

`<form method="post" action="testformQ.php">
  <input type="text" name="testform">
  <input type="submit">enter`

Page 2 Query

```
'$software = mysql_query("SELECT software.SoftwareID, rooms.RoomID 
    FROM softwareroom 
    INNER JOIN software 
    ON software.SoftwareID=softwareroom.SoftwareID 
    INNER JOIN rooms ON rooms.RoomID=softwareroom.RoomID 
    WHERE rooms.RoomNum=$_GET[testform]");              (the where clause is where i want the variable)
        while($rec = mysql_fetch_array($software))
        {
            echo $rec['SoftwareID'] . " " . $rec['RoomID'];
        }'
```

So where the GET testform is within the query is where I want the form variable to go.
Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Why avoid mysql_* functions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you

```
$data = $_REQUEST['testform'];

$software = mysql_query("SELECT software.SoftwareID, rooms.RoomID 
    FROM softwareroom 
    INNER JOIN software 
    ON software.SoftwareID=softwareroom.SoftwareID 
    INNER JOIN rooms ON rooms.RoomID=softwareroom.RoomID 
    WHERE rooms.RoomNum='$data'");        
    while($rec = mysql_fetch_array($software))
        {
            echo $rec['SoftwareID'] . " " . $rec['RoomID'];
        }'
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked but now I am having problems displaying the result of the query any idea how I might do that?

Comment: at the place of echo $rec['SoftwareID'] . " " . $rec['RoomID']; you can use print_r($rec);

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\testformQ.php on line 17
Getting this error 
17)while($rec = mysql_fetch_array($software))
18)   {
19)    print_r($rec);
   }

Comment: sorry its my mistake in coding.now you can use my code i have edit it in line $software = mysql_query("SELECT software.SoftwareID, rooms.RoomID .

Comment: I still get the same errorWarning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\testformQ.php on line 17

Comment: have you use $con = mysql_connect('localhost','username','password'); mysql_select_db("dbname", $con); at top of page 2?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Page02 Query..

```
    $servername = "servername";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $db = "db_name";

    $query = "SELECT software.SoftwareID, rooms.RoomID FROM softwareroom INNER JOIN software ON software.SoftwareID = softwareroom.SoftwareID"
            + "INNER JOIN rooms ON rooms.RoomID = softwareroom.RoomID WHERE rooms.RoomNum = '$_POST["testform"]'";

    //Create db connection
    $connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

    //Check connection
    if(!$connection){
        echo "Failed to connect to database ".mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $software = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    mysqli_close($connection);
```